# Join PySpark dataframes with unequal numbers of rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two PySpark dataframe which are as given underneath

First is `df1` which is given below:

```
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
| name| type|timestamp1|score|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
|name1|type1|2012-01-10|   11|
|name2|type1|2012-01-10|   14|
|name3|type2|2012-01-10|    2|
|name3|type2|2012-01-17|    3|
|name1|type1|2012-01-18|   55|
|name1|type1|2012-01-19|   10|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
```

Second is `df2` which is given below:

```
+-----+-------------------+-------+-------+
| name|         timestamp2|string1|string2|
+-----+-------------------+-------+-------+
|name1|2012-01-10 00:00:00|      A|     aa|
|name2|2012-01-10 00:00:00|      A|     bb|
|name3|2012-01-10 00:00:00|      C|     cc|
|name4|2012-01-17 00:00:00|      D|     dd|
|name3|2012-01-10 00:00:00|      C|     cc|
|name2|2012-01-17 00:00:00|      A|     bb|
|name2|2012-01-17 00:00:00|      A|     bb|
|name4|2012-01-10 00:00:00|      D|     dd|
|name3|2012-01-17 00:00:00|      C|     cc|
+-----+-------------------+-------+-------+
```

These two dataframes have one common column, *i.e.* `name`. Each unique value of `name` in `df2` has unique values of `string1` and `string2`.

I want to join `df1` and `df2` and form a new dataframe `df3` such that `df3` contains all the rows of `df1` (same structure, numbers of rows as `df1`) but assigns values from columns `string1` and `string2` (from `df2`) to appropriate values of `name` in `df1`. Following is how I want the combined dataframe (`df3`) to look like.

```
+-----+-----+----------+-----+-------+-------+
| name| type|timestamp1|score|string1|string2|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+-------+-------+
|name1|type1|2012-01-10|   11|      A|     aa|
|name2|type1|2012-01-10|   14|      A|     bb|
|name3|type2|2012-01-10|    2|      C|     cc|
|name3|type2|2012-01-17|    3|      C|     cc|
|name1|type1|2012-01-18|   55|      A|     aa|
|name1|type1|2012-01-19|   10|      A|     aa|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+-------+-------+
```

**How can I do get the above mentioned dataframe (`df3`)?**

I tried the following `df3 = df1.join( df2.select("name", "string1", "string2") , on=["name"], how="left")`. But that gives me a dataframe with 14 rows with multiple (duplicate) entries of rows.

You can use the below mentioned code to generate `df1` and `df2`.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1_Stats = Row("name", "type", "timestamp1", "score")

df1_stat1 = df1_Stats('name1', 'type1', "2012-01-10", 11)
df1_stat2 = df1_Stats('name2', 'type1', "2012-01-10", 14)
df1_stat3 = df1_Stats('name3', 'type2', "2012-01-10", 2)
df1_stat4 = df1_Stats('name3', 'type2', "2012-01-17", 3)
df1_stat5 = df1_Stats('name1', 'type1', "2012-01-18", 55)
df1_stat6 = df1_Stats('name1', 'type1', "2012-01-19", 10)

df1_stat_lst = [df1_stat1 , df1_stat2, df1_stat3, df1_stat4, df1_stat5, df1_stat6]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1_stat_lst)

df2_Stats = Row("name", "timestamp2", "string1", "string2")

df2_stat1 = df2_Stats("name1", "2012-01-10 00:00:00", "A", "aa")
df2_stat2 = df2_Stats("name2", "2012-01-10 00:00:00", "A", "bb")
df2_stat3 = df2_Stats("name3", "2012-01-10 00:00:00", "C", "cc")
df2_stat4 = df2_Stats("name4", "2012-01-17 00:00:00", "D", "dd")
df2_stat5 = df2_Stats("name3", "2012-01-10 00:00:00", "C", "cc")
df2_stat6 = df2_Stats("name2", "2012-01-17 00:00:00", "A", "bb")
df2_stat7 = df2_Stats("name2", "2012-01-17 00:00:00", "A", "bb")
df2_stat8 = df2_Stats("name4", "2012-01-10 00:00:00", "D", "dd")
df2_stat9 = df2_Stats("name3", "2012-01-17 00:00:00", "C", "cc")

df2_stat_lst = [
    df2_stat1,
    df2_stat2,
    df2_stat3,
    df2_stat4,
    df2_stat5,
    df2_stat6,
    df2_stat7,
    df2_stat8,
    df2_stat9,
]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2_stat_lst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to remove duplicates before joining , making small table to join.

```
 df3 = df1.join(df2.select("name", "string1", "string2").distinct(),on=["name"] , how="left")
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the following technique does it:

```
df3 = df1.join(
    df2.select("name", "string1", "string2"), on=["name"], how="left"
).dropDuplicates()
df3.show()

+-----+-----+----------+-----+-------+-------+
| name| type| timestamp|score|string1|string2|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+-------+-------+
|name2|type1|2012-01-10|   14|      A|     bb|
|name3|type2|2012-01-10|    2|      C|     cc|
|name1|type1|2012-01-18|   55|      A|     aa|
|name1|type1|2012-01-10|   11|      A|     aa|
|name3|type2|2012-01-17|    3|      C|     cc|
|name1|type1|2012-01-19|   10|      A|     aa|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+-------+-------+
```

I am still open for answers. So, if you have a more efficient method of answering the question, please feel free to drop your answer.